# Реализация вызова кастомного метода 'method' у любой ф-ии конструктора

Tags: javascript, объекты, конструктор

Этот метод принимает имя метода и его реализацию. При создании объекта с помощью этой функции конструктора у него будут методы заданные с помощью 'method'.

Пример:

```js
Person.method('getName', function () {
    return this.name;
  }).method('setSurname', function (surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
  }).method('getFullName', function () {
    return this.surname + ' ' + this.name;
  });

var person = new Person('Alex');
console.log(person);
person.setSurname('Sins');
console.log(person.getName());
console.log(person.getFullName());
```

Вообще не понимаю как реализовать этот метод. Может кто может подсказать?

Answer (score -1):

```js
var Person = function(name){
  this.name=name;
}
Person.method = (name, func) => (Person.prototype[name] = func, Person);


Person.method('getName', function () {
    return this.name;
  }).method('setSurname', function (surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
  }).method('getFullName', function () {
    return this.surname + ' ' + this.name;
  });

var person = new Person('Alex');
console.log(person);
person.setSurname('Sins');
console.log(person.getName());
console.log(person.getFullName());
```